# Multiplication in R

Tags: r, multiplication

I have a huge data set. Data covers around 4000 regions.

I need to do a multiplication like this: each number in each row should be multiplied by the corresponding column name/value (0 or...) at first. 
Then, these resulting numbers should be summed up and be divided by total number (totaln) in that row.

For example, the data is like this:

```
region    totan   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     .....
1         1346    5    7    3    9    23   24   34   54    .....
2         1256    7    8    4    10   34   2    14   30    .....
3         1125    83   43   23   11   16   4    67   21    .....
4         3211    43   21   67   12   13   12   98   12    .....
5         1111    21   8    9     3   23   13   11    0    .....
....      ....    ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..    .....
4000      2345    21   9    11   45   67   89   28   7     .....
```

The calculation should be like this:

For example in region 1: 
(5*0)+(7*1)+(3*2)+(9*3)+(23*4)+(24*5)+(34*6)+(7*54)...= the result/1346=the result

I need to do such an analysis for all the regions. 
I tried a couple of ways like use of "for" and "apply" but did not get the required result.

Comment: from your comments here and on other answers, it seems like your example data isn't reflective of your actual data. Can you do a little digging and figure out what parts of your real data aren't numeric? If you need more help, posting `str(your_data)` will help us figure out what classes you are using.

Comment: @Gregor, I checked it and it tells that except for region that is characteristic, all other data are integer. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: I mean, you're the one getting "non-numeric" errors, so there is a problem. Maybe the problem is in  `as.numeric(names(df)[3:10])`? Are you column names really as you show?

Comment: From what you've shared, we can only make guesses based on what your data looks like. If you post `str(your_data)` then we could really help figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tidyverse :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather(k,v,-region,-totan) %>%
  group_by(region,totan) %>% summarize(x=sum(as.numeric(k)*v)/first(totan))
## A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   region [?]
#  region totan     x
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
#1      1  1346 0.620
#2      2  1256 0.387
#3      3  1125 0.671
#4      4  3211 0.304
#5      5  1111 0.232
```

Comment: Thanks. It brings back this error: could not find function "%>%". @Nicolas2

Comment: You need magrittr, tidyr and dplyr : load the `tidyverse` package to get them all and some other too.

Comment: This works, thanks. I have to just save it as a new df. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done fully vectorized:

Data:

```
> df
  region totan  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1      1  1346  5  7  3  9 23 24 34 54
2      2  1256  7  8  4 10 34  2 14 30
3      3  1125 83 43 23 11 16  4 67 21
4      4  3211 43 21 67 12 13 12 98 12
5      5  1111 21  8  9  3 23 13 11  0
6   4000  2345 21  9 11 45 67 89 28  7

as.matrix(df[3:10]) %*% as.numeric(names(df)[3:10]) / df$totan

          [,1]
[1,] 0.6196137
[2,] 0.3869427
[3,] 0.6711111
[4,] 0.3036437
[5,] 0.2322232
[6,] 0.4673774
```

This should be significantly faster on a huge dataset than any `for` or `*apply` loop.

Comment: Thanks. It brings back this error: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.

Comment: If you still want to try this solution for the speed, please provide an example of your data that includes classes, best by using `dput(yourdata[1:10, 1:6])` and pasting the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    sum(data[i,3:(ncol(data))]*names(data)[3:ncol(data)])/data[i,2]
}
```

alternatively

```
apply(data,1,function(x){
    sum(x[3:length(x)]*names(x)[3:length(x)])/x[2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For the first one, it brings back this error: Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator.